# Location - PHP - загрузка файла

Tags: php

Посылаю файл на загрузку таким образом:

```
    $mp4url = "http://www.site.tv/video.mp4";
header('Location: '.$mp4url);
```

В Chrome происходит редирект на адрес файла. Как ему вдолбить загрузку на компьютер, а не проигрывание в браузере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Modify HTTP Headers (Examples)](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/headers.htm)

Answer (score 1):

тогда вам как вариант: через функцию php, кторая сохраняет файлы (запамятовал как она) сохраняете файл у себя на сервере, а затем используете мою функцию форсирования загрузки со своего сервера

[Функция форсированной загрузки файлов](http://subcoder.ru/%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8/)

Comment: Если пробовать указать путь до файла на другом сервере, то он просто пишет "Ошибка: Файл не найден.", в ином случае все нормально.
Но мне нужно скачать файл с другого сервера.
Но все равно спасибо. :)

Comment: и не получится на другом сервере, хедеры надо сформировать :)

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать в **.htaccess**:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .mp4
```

Comment: Не помогло, все равно происходит редирект. Также я извиняюсь, написал не тот код. Вот код, с помощью которого я все осуществлял: <code>$mp4url = "http://www.site.tv/video.mp4";
header('Location: '.$mp4url);</code>

Comment: Тогда в htaccess напиши <br>
AddType audio/mpeg .mp4

Comment: Ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 0):

это все на стороне клиента настраивается, на сервере ничего не изменить, разве что архивом посылать

Comment: Ну тогда каким это образом получается скачивание файлов сайта в ISPmanager, причем любых форматов? :) Все решается на стороне сервера, но вот как правильно написать код - вот что меня интересует.

Comment: http://www.sdaprel.ru/content/view/679/54/

http://forum.vingrad.ru/topic-34891.html

попробуйте эти варианты.

Думаю если в заголовок Content-type прописать: application/octet-stream будет закачиваться, а не проигрываться. Ведь браузер смотрит на тип файла.